# Bilstm Keras multilabel classification : predict the same value for each token

Tags: python-3.x, keras, bilstm

I have made a bi lstm and I would like to be able to predict new values with it, i.e. I would like to have the corresponding labels in output. However, I notice that I always get the same value. Do you know why? Did I make a mistake in my settings? You can see in the first picture my bi-lstm and in the second picture the predictions. Tanhk you!!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a multilabel classification?

Comment: Yes i have 7 labels

Comment: I suppose you confuse multiclass classification with multilabel classification.

Comment: For each of token, I would like to know if it belongs to one of the 7 possible labels. Do you think the problem I have is related to my confusion?

Comment: Yes, model configuration is not correct. Last should have `softmax` activation and loss needs to be `categorical_crossentropy` if labels are one-hot-encoded, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, I made the modifications, I have new values but I still have the same problem when I do predicted.argmax, I have the same values:

Comment: Oh I may have misunderstood, can there be multiple labels in predictions like [1 0 1 1 0 ..] or is it one label at a time like [0 0 0 0 1 ... ] ?

Comment: Like [0 0 0 0 1] :)

Comment: Ok then now it is correct with softmax. The problem could be the data, is it skewed?

Comment: Indeed, I have an overrepresentation of one label compared to the others. How should I configure my bilstm in this case ? Thank you very much for your answers and your expertise!!

Comment: Well, the model configuration is correct with softmax + cross entropy. What you ask now is not a programming question. There are several ways to deal with class imbalance, you can check for class weights and focal loss.